# Threading: Restarting a thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have a django project that I am currently working on. I have several threads that I use to fill a database through API requests when the user asks for a database update using a button. This works great.

My problem is that I would like users to be able to refresh the database more than once while the server is active (in the future). Since threads can't be restarted once they finish, I'm not really sure how to proceed to achieve what I want. Here are my threads:

```
agencies_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_agencies, name="Database Updater1")
companies_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_companies, name="Database Updater2")
contracts_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_contracts, name="Database Updater3")
orders_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_orders, name="Database Updater4")
projects_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_projects, name="Database Updater5")
resources_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_resources, name="Database Updater6")
```

I'm thinking that the threads have to be recreated everytime someones presses the button, but adding those lines ^^ in my views.py function that manages the database loading can't really work considering my function:

```
elif urlRequest[:12] == 'loading.html':    # PAGE DE CHARGEMENT
    global updateValue
    if updateValue == 0:
        agencies_thread.start()
        companies_thread.start()
        contracts_thread.start()
        orders_thread.start()
        projects_thread.start()
        resources_thread.start()
        updateValue = 1
    updateState = 0
    if agencies_thread.is_alive():
        agenciesState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        agenciesState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if companies_thread.is_alive():
        companiesState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        companiesState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if contracts_thread.is_alive():
        contractsState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        contractsState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if orders_thread.is_alive():
        ordersState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        ordersState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if projects_thread.is_alive():
        projectsState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        projectsState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if resources_thread.is_alive():
        resourcesState = 'en cours de chargement'
    else:
        resourcesState = 'Chargement terminé'
        updateState += 1
    if updateState == 6:
        updateValue = 0
        context['updateState'] = 'Base de données mise à jour.'
        html_template = loader.get_template('index.html')
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
    else:
        context['agenciesState'] = agenciesState
        context['companiesState'] = companiesState
        context['contractsState'] = contractsState
        context['ordersState'] = ordersState
        context['projectsState'] = projectsState
        context['resourcesState'] = resourcesState
        html_template = loader.get_template('loading.html')
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

I'm thinking that maybe I need to have a global variable (like `updateState`) with an `ìf` condition to recreate the threads.
What do you think about this?

Comment: You need to separate the idea of a "thread" from the work that it does. You have something called `contracts_thread` that (I am guessing) is two things at the same time: It's a list of contracts, \*and\* it's a thread. You can't re-use a thread, but there's no reason why you should not be able to re-use a list of contracts. You need to re-factor your program so that every time you want to process the list of contracts, you create a new thread, and you give it the same old `contracts` object. (i.e., you create a thread that calls a function that operates on the contracts.)

Comment: ```contract_thread``` actually calls a function that doesn't return anything : it fills a database. Accessing that database isn't a problem, it 's just that I want to recall that function in parallel of other things. (I managed to figure out a way to do it, even though it might not be the prettiest)

Comment: OK, but my point was, that the thread _object_ and the object containing the data upon which the thread works should be two different objects. Then it becomes easy to re-use the data object in any number of different threads.

Comment: Yes I understand your point. But my problem was not the data. It was the thread. I didn't need to re-use the data created, but the process in which it was created. But all good now!

Comment: OK, I didn't understand. If it was the thread, then it never really was a problem. There is no reason why you should ever want to re-use a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a global variable 'threading state' and using it to recreate the threads within the function worked. I just had to declare the threads as global variables at the start of the function, otherwise I would get an error.